# Sealing foundation blocks and gap between drywall

Tags: garage, sealing, cinderblock

I am trying to paint my garage and noticed that there are gaps where drywall meets cinder blocks and between drywall and concrete slab in the garage. Is there a way I can seal and paint the cinder blocks to make it look uniform. Also it makes life easy by not holding on to dust and cob webs when the blocks are sealed, not to mention the ease of cleaning with water when needed.
Whenever I do some woodwork in the garage, its a challenge to clean the area, on top it the blocks appear to absorb water when washed with hose.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the exact reason you touched upon you don't want to bring those two components together. The drywall will leach water from the concrete, breaking it down and creating stains.

Instead, finish each separately with appropriate paint and use a plastic T-molding or other transition to cover the seam. I'd consider using the epoxy that I see on your slab to do the block.

Comment: Could you please explain "plastic T-molding or other transition" and also epoxy?  Could you share sample links or images?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Google shows some great examples of a "plastic T-molding". Epoxy refers to the floor coating shown in the photos. Several companies make good options.

Comment: Thanks.  So you insert the little thing that sticks out in the gap between the two parts, and let the symmetrical parts cover the edges of the two things that are butting together?  Okay, I think I get that. //  I know "epoxy" as a special adhesive that you make by mixing two substances together with a special dual syringe sort of thing.  Is that what you're talking about?  Is it waterproof -- is that why you recommend it?

Comment: I don't think you can trust the gap to retain the T-molding's installation strip since it won't be consistently the right size. You'd need to use panel adhesive or something in addition. Search "epoxy floor paint" to learn about that.

Comment: I don't get it.  Are you arguing against your own recommendation?

Comment: I did not recommend installing the molding as you described. I can't offer specific advice not knowing what products you have at your disposal.

Comment: We're talking at cross purposes here.  I'm sorry.  I don't have this specific problem as described by OP.  I'm trying to understand the shorthand in the answer.

Comment: No worries. I deliberately left things vague in this particular answer because it's largely left to the prerogative and options available to the installer. If you like, post your own question with specifics and we'll tackle it.

Comment: I don't have a variant of this question, I'm just trying to understand what you wrote.  Right now I'm pretty confused, why you recommended a plastic T-molding in the answer and then in the comments your opinion sounded somewhat different.  But I'm not really sure what you were saying in the comments.  Here, how's this: This answer would be strengthened by explaining the ideas and terminology so that an inexperienced DIYer can understand what was written.